# how to get old and new files in a single LINQ query or any other better way

Tags: c#

Currently using below method I am returning `IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>` which returns all the files less than X days old.

```
private static IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry> GetFiles(ZipArchive archive, int days)
    {
        return archive.Entries
            .Where(y => y.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days))
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);
    }
```

Now I want to return `count` of files as well which are greater than X days old.

I want to return both `IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>` (less than X days old) and `count` (greater than X days old) in a single method, how to achieve this with best optimal way?

I tried below: can I do something in single `where` LINQ query?

```
private static (IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>, int count) GetFiles(ZipArchive archive, int days)
    {
        var entries = archive.Entries
            .Where(y => y.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days))
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);

        var count = archive.Entries
            .Where(y => y.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days))
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime).ToList().Count;

        return (entries, count);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `var count = archive.Entries.Except(entries).Count();`. Also 1, no need to `..OrderBy`  when you just need the `.Count`. Also 2, The `Enumerable` has `Count()` method so you don't need to create a list (`.ToList()`) to get the count.

Comment: Actually, it's just `var count = archive.Entries.Count - entries.Count();`. So `return (entries, archive.Entries.Count - entries.Count());`. Keep it simple. A one liner means more methods to call. Math is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it be possible with single LINQ?

If you insist/mean to have it in one-liner:

```cs
private static (IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>, int count) GetFiles(ZipArchive archive, int days)
    => (archive.Entries
        .Where(x => x.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days))
        .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime), archive.Entries
        .Count(x => x.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days)));
```

Where the suggested code snippet is more efficient because you don't need to call more methods...

```cs
private static (IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>, int count) GetFiles(ZipArchive archive, int days)
{
    var entries = archive.Entries
        .Where(y => y.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days))
        .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);

    return (entries, archive.Entries.Count - entries.Count());
}
```

Either way, the method's return type doesn't make any sense to me since the caller can simply subtract the `IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry>` that returns from the `>` condition from the `archive.Entries`.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var entries = archive.Entries
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);
            .Select(x => new {
                 totalcount = x.Count,
                 files = x.Where(y => y.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days),
                 newfileCount = x.Where(y => y.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days)).Count,
            });
```

Comment: when `y.LastWriteTime > DateTime` I want files and when `y.LastWriteTime < DateTime I want count. Both condition I need to check and return combined result. I am using 2 different LINQ, will it be possible with single LINQ?